# How can I insert multiple numbers to a particular element of a vector?

Tags: c++, vector, stdvector

I am quite new to C++ and vector. I am calculating two things say 'i' and 'x' and I want to add 'x' that belongs to a particular vector element 'i'. I learned that if I have one 'x' value, I can simply do that by 'vec.at(i) = x'. But what if I want to add several 'x' values to a particular 'i' index of a vector?

Let's try to make it clear: Let's say I am searching for number '5' and '3' over a list of numbers from 1 to 10 (5 and 3 can occur multiple times in the list) and each time I am looking for number 5 or 3 that belong to index '2' of 'vec' I can do 'vec.at(2) = 5' or 'vec.at(2) = 3'. Then what if I have two '5' values and two '3' values so the sum of the index '2' of 'vec' will be '5+5+3+3' = 16?

P.S: using a counter and multiply concept will not solve my problem as the real problem is quite complicated. This query is just an example only. I want a solution within vector concept. I appreciate your help in advance.

Comment: C does not have vectors.  Please only tag the language you are using.

Comment: "Let's try to make it even more clear" you failed. Try to make it just clear, not even more clear.

Comment: So, are you trying to set two values in the same indexed-position of a vector? That's not possible.

Comment: Explaining is difficult if you don't know what can be done. First, start off with what you have, e.g. a list of numbers. Then, describe what you want to do with those numbers, in small and unambiguous steps.

Comment: You may want std::vector<std::list<int>>

Comment: Your question is a bit unclear, but have you looked at [insert](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/insert) or [emplace](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/emplace)?

Comment: I wanted to have something like 'vec[i].push_back(x)'. So that I can put any numbers at index 'i' of 'vec' and later I can do any operation with the numbers stored in 'i'.
But as @Ripi2 said, it is not possible. Thank you, everyone, for your time.

Comment: If you want to have a list of values in the same position use @drescherjm comment (a vector of list's)

Comment: @Ripi2 Yes, could you be so kind to explain a bit on 'vector of vectors'? How can I solve that using 'vector of vectors'. That would be cool!

Comment: @drescherjm: Can you please share some link where I can look in detail?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know how many indices you want ahead of time, then try `std::vector<std::vector<int>>` (or instead of `int` use `double` or whatever).

For instance, if you want a collection of numbers corresponding to each number from 0 to 9, try

```
//This creates the vector of vectors, 
//of length 10 (i.e. indices [0,9])
//with an empty vector for each element.
std::vector<std::vector<int>> vec(10, std::vector<int>());
```

To insert an element at a given index (assuming that there is something there, so in the above case there is only 'something there' for elements 0 through 9), try

```
vec.at(1).push_back(5);
vec.at(1).push_back(3);
```

And then to take the sum of the numbers in the vector at index 1:

```
int sum = 0;
for (int elem : vec.at(1)) { sum += elem; }
//sum should now be 8
```

If you want it to work for arbitrary indices, then it should be

```
std::map<int, std::vector<int>> map;
map[1].push_back(5); //creates an empty vector at index 1, then inserts
map[1].push_back(3); //uses the existing vector at index 1
int sum = 0;
for (int elem : map.at(1)) { sum += elem; }
```

Note that for `std::vector` and `std::map`, using `[]` do very different things.  Most of the time you want `at`, which is about the same for both, but in this very specific case, `[]` for `std::map` is a good choice.

EDIT: To sum over every element in every vector in the map, you need an outer loop to go through the vectors in the map (paired with their index) and an inner loop like the one above.  For example:

```
int sum = 0;
for (const std::pair<int, std::vector<int>>& index_vec : map) {
  for (int elem : index_vec.second) { sum += elem; }
}
```

Comment: Wow! this is awesome! Thanks @hegel5000 for the solution. This is what I exactly wanted. :)

Comment: Sorry for asking another query. What if I want to have a loop (and sum all the elements) over all the indices of map? Should it be then 'for (int elem : map.at(i)) { sum += elem; }' ?

Comment: @baban No problem.  See edit.  It's not entirely obvious from the documentation I've seen that `std::map`'s elements, when you loop over it, are `std::pair`s, and it took me a while to figure that out originally.

Comment: Thanks! But what I meant is if I have something like this `map[1].push_back(5); //creates an empty vector at index 1, then inserts
 map[1].push_back(3); //uses the existing vector at index 1
 map[3].push_back(2);
 map[2].push_back(1);` then I want an output: `index 1: 8, index 2: 1, index 3: 2` NOT the sum of all i.e. 11.

Comment: In that case you'd declare and initialize your `sum` variable inside the outer loop, which will reset it to zero for each (int, vector) pair.  You can then print with `std::cout << "index " << index_vec.first << ": " << sum << std::endl;`.

Comment: Hi, the entire code works absolutely fine in my laptop, but when I run it in my desktop it says `error: expected initializer before ‘:’ token` which corresponds to `for (const pair<int, vector<int> >& index_vec : map)` this line. Any idea?

Comment: That's possibly a matter of your compiler not being set for C++11/14/17 mode.  Compilers and build systems are beyond me.